# Pass data from jQuery to php file

Tags: php, jquery

Hello I have this code

```
$('.preview a').click(function() {
  $('.presentation > .images > .margin').load('images.php');

  return false; 
});
```

Is there possibility to pass data from jquery into that images.php file and then let's say echo that data? I've tried everything I suppose so, but nothing seemed to work. Could anybody help me with it, if it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could encode the data into the url. Assume you want to send the string `Hello` to the server, you could do the following:

```
$('.presentation > .images > .margin').load('images.php?v=Hello');
```

In `PHP`, you can access the string `Hello` via `$_GET['v']`.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the Tomasz Nguyen answer, if you want to pass data via POST method you can do this:

```
$('.preview a').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: 'images.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {foo:value}
   }).done(function(response){
       $('.presentation > .images > .margin').html(response);
   });
});
```

You can read the foo var in images.php with `$_POST['foo']` and build your response to append inside  `$('.presentation > .images > .margin')`

If you want to pass the var via get method, just change the `type` parameter to `'GET'`